# ubutun 18.04 I did master and slave replication. before it was working fine but today it stopped all of a sudden I don't know why

Tags: mysql, replication

2022-04-27T21:57:22.421118Z 2 [ERROR] Slave I/O for channel '': error connecting to master 'replicat@172.20.10.2:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 1, Error_code: 2003
2022-04-27T21:58:22.810750Z 2 [ERROR] Slave I/O for channel '': error connecting to master 'replicat@172.20.10.2:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 2, Error_code: 2003
2022-04-27T21:59:32.829817Z 2 [Note] Slave I/O thread for channel '': connected to master 'replicat@172.20.10.2:3306',replication started in log 'mysql-bin.015427' at position 154
2022-04-27T21:59:32.846451Z 2 [ERROR] Error reading packet from server for channel '': Could not find first log file name in binary log index file (server_errno=1236)
2022-04-27T21:59:32.846487Z 2 [ERROR] Slave I/O for channel '': Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log: 'Could not find first log file name in binary log index file', Error_co$
2022-04-27T21:59:32.846493Z 2 [Note] Slave I/O thread exiting for channel '', read up to log 'mysql-bin.015427', position 154

Comment: "Could not find first log file name in binary log index file'" is why. Off topic.

Comment: It was off topic for Stack Overflow at it wasn't a programming question. It is on topic here on dba.stackexchange. What does `show master status` on the master show?

Comment: What changed?  Diff server?  Diff Port?  Missing GRANT?